# Counting difference of two dates in a PL SQL FUNCTION, should be returing number of days

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following output:

| from_date | until_date |
| --- | --- |
| 17.03.2020 | 18.05.2020 |
| 18.05.2020 | 08.06.2020 |
| 21.12.2020 | 01.03.2021 |
| 01.03.2021 | 11.03.2021 |
| 19.10.2021 | 22.10.2021 |
| 10.01.2022 | 14.01.2022 |
| 14.01.2022 | NULL |

I need to count the days between these two dates, second date inclusively, with this logic:

```
(18.05.2020 -  17.03.2020)+1 = 63
```

The next row begins at the same day as it ends in the first row,
then the `18.05.2020` must not be counted in the  days difference, so:

```
08.06.2020 - 18.05.2020
```

if the `until_date` is `null` then it will be:

```
sysdate-from_date
```

but what im struggling to do is to get next element and previous element values in a loop so I can compare them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `LAG` analytic function to find the previous `until_date`:

```sql
SELECT from_date,
       until_date,
       COALESCE(until_date, TRUNC(SYSDATE)) - from_date
         + CASE
           WHEN LAG(until_date) OVER (ORDER BY FROM_DATE) = from_date
           THEN 0
           ELSE 1
           END
         AS difference
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (from_date, until_date) AS
SELECT DATE '2020-03-17', DATE '2020-05-18' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-05-18', DATE '2020-06-08' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-12-21', DATE '2021-03-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-03-01', DATE '2021-03-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-10-19', DATE '2021-10-22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-01-10', DATE '2022-01-14' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-01-14', NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | FROM_DATE | UNTIL_DATE | DIFFERENCE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2020-03-17 00:00:00 | 2020-05-18 00:00:00 | 63 |
> | 2020-05-18 00:00:00 | 2020-06-08 00:00:00 | 21 |
> | 2020-12-21 00:00:00 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 | 71 |
> | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 | 2021-03-11 00:00:00 | 10 |
> | 2021-10-19 00:00:00 | 2021-10-22 00:00:00 | 4 |
> | 2022-01-10 00:00:00 | 2022-01-14 00:00:00 | 5 |
> | 2022-01-14 00:00:00 | *null* | 154 |

If you want it in PL/SQL then wrap the query in a cursor and loop through the cursor in PL/SQL.

```sql
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (
    SELECT from_date,
           until_date,
           COALESCE(until_date, TRUNC(SYSDATE)) - from_date
             + CASE
               WHEN LAG(until_date) OVER (ORDER BY FROM_DATE) = from_date
               THEN 0
               ELSE 1
               END
             AS difference
    FROM   table_name
  ) LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( r.from_date || ', ' || r.until_date || ', ' || r.difference );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Or you can do exactly the same thing by storing the previous `until_date` in a PL/SQL variable:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_until_date DATE;
  v_diff       NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (
    SELECT from_date,
           until_date
    FROM   table_name
    ORDER BY from_date
  ) LOOP
    v_diff := COALESCE(r.until_date, TRUNC(SYSDATE)) - r.from_date
            + CASE WHEN v_until_date = r.from_date THEN 0 ELSE 1 END;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
      r.from_date
      || ', ' || r.until_date
      || ', ' || v_diff
    );
    v_until_date := r.until_date;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=50dc6726775073b0512852596ffade67)*